# Version number of an app , when app name changed?

Tags: ios

I want to change my app name with an update , will the version number be 1.0 or the next one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about app that already exists in the app store and you are about to update in iTunes Connect with a new binary and a new name, the version number is up to you. But the app's `Info.plist` must have *the next one* or it will be rejected. So keep things easy and use the same numbering scheme in both, using for instance `1.1.0`.

Comment: ok then when the app name has changed , will the link of app be changed ?

Comment: Yes and no. The link is different but the old one will work because what matters is the app id, and that doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is follow the convention for version numbering. It is generally major.minor.revision. There's no real standard when you change the name, so it's really up to you. You could say it's some sort of revision, or you could say it's a new app and start from 1.0. Below is a link to version numbering so you can see.

[Version Numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning)